# How to get the actual data inside ._raw from fetch() query result in WatermelonDB?

Tags: javascript, database, react-native, watermelondb

I do have a single query like this:

```
const rows = await db.active.collections
    .get('messages')
    .query(
            Q.where('status', messagesStatus.ERROR)
     ).fetch()
```

the results is like this:

```
[
  {
     __changes: Object,
   isEditing: false,
   preparedState: null,
   _raw: MY ACTUAL DATA
  },
  {
     __changes: Object,
   isEditing: false,
   preparedState: null,
   _raw: MY ACTUAL DATA
  },
]
```

I can use map to get ._raw data but I dont think it is a good idea. Any insight?

Answer (score -2):

I don't see any issue with that as long as you don't mutate the returned objects as the docs [here](https://nozbe.github.io/WatermelonDB/Query.html?highlight=mutate#unsafe-fetch-raw).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33538264)